# Applying custom function while grouping returns NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, series

Given a dict, `performances`, storing Series of kind:

```
2015-02-28           NaN
2015-03-02    100.000000
2015-03-03     98.997117
2015-03-04     98.909215
2015-03-05     99.909979
2015-03-06    100.161486
2015-03-09    100.502772
2015-03-10    101.685314
2015-03-11    102.518433
2015-03-12    102.427237
2015-03-13    103.424257
2015-03-16    102.669184
2015-03-17    102.181841
2015-03-18    102.436339
2015-03-19    102.672482
2015-03-20    102.238386
2015-03-23    101.460082
...
```

I want to group them by month, but only pick the first value which is not `np.nan`, for each month's data set:

```
for perf in performance:
    performance[perf] = performance[perf].groupby(performance[perf].index.month).apply(return_first)


def return_first(array_like):
    # Return data from 1st of month, or first value that is not np.nan
    for i in range(len(array_like)):
        if np.isnan(array_like[i]):
            continue
        else:
            return(array_like[i])
```

This, however returns nan values:

```
2015-02-28   NaN
2015-03-02   NaN
2015-03-03   NaN
2015-03-04   NaN
2015-03-05   NaN
2015-03-06   NaN
2015-03-09   NaN
2015-03-10   NaN
2015-03-11   NaN
2015-03-12   NaN
2015-03-13   NaN
2015-03-16   NaN
2015-03-17   NaN
2015-03-18   NaN
2015-03-19   NaN
2015-03-20   NaN
2015-03-23   NaN
...
```

When it should have been:

```
2015-03-02   100   
...
```

I cannot suspect my index, which seems to be a prefectly fine `pd.DateTimeIndex`:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2015-02-28', '2015-03-02', '2015-03-03', '2015-03-04',
           '2015-03-05', '2015-03-06', '2015-03-09', '2015-03-10',
           '2015-03-11', '2015-03-12',
           ...
           '2016-02-16', '2016-02-17', '2016-02-18', '2016-02-19',
           '2016-02-22', '2016-02-23', '2016-02-24', '2016-02-25',
           '2016-02-26', '2016-02-29'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=265, freq=None)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: can you post a desired output/result set?

Comment: Added it just now, using example dataset. Essentially, all values except the first value != `nan` in each month should be thrown away.

Comment: What will `return_first` do if all the values are `NaN`? Can you tell us what is in `performances` (or `performance`) or provide a small example that demonstrates the same behaviour?

Comment: Why not use [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html)?

Comment: @doctorlove, I've given an example of what's in performances ( see above). `return_first` won't return anything if all values are `nan`.
@IanS, because I didn't know about that - but it appears to be a `DataFrame`, not a `Series` method?

Comment: If you want to see a longer example of the data I use, [look here](http://pastebin.com/jyJkDN9d)

Comment: Does MaxU's answer below work? If not you should leave him a comment...

Comment: Trying it, but it gives me an `AssertionError: Grouper and axis must be same length` - probably due to the fact that I have a `Series`, and not a `DataFrame`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each month has at least one non `NaN` value, use [`first_valid_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html):

```
print (df.b.groupby(df.index.month).apply(lambda x: x[x.first_valid_index()]))
```

More general solution, which return `NaN` if all values in some month are `NaN`:

```
def f(x):
    if x.first_valid_index() is None:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x[x.first_valid_index()]

print (df.b.groupby(df.index.month).apply(f))

2      NaN
3    100.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

If you want group by `years` and `months` use [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html):

```
print (df.b.groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).apply(f))
2015-02      NaN
2015-03    100.0
Freq: M, Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'b': pd.Series({ pd.Timestamp('2015-07-19 00:00:00'): 102.67248199999999,  pd.Timestamp('2015-04-05 00:00:00'):  np.nan,  pd.Timestamp('2015-02-25 00:00:00'):  np.nan,  pd.Timestamp('2015-04-09 00:00:00'): 100.50277199999999,  pd.Timestamp('2015-06-18 00:00:00'): 102.436339,  pd.Timestamp('2015-06-16 00:00:00'): 102.669184,  pd.Timestamp('2015-04-10 00:00:00'): 101.68531400000001,  pd.Timestamp('2015-05-12 00:00:00'): 102.42723700000001,  pd.Timestamp('2015-07-20 00:00:00'): 102.23838600000001,  pd.Timestamp('2015-06-17 00:00:00'):  np.nan,  pd.Timestamp('2015-08-23 00:00:00'): 101.460082,  pd.Timestamp('2015-03-03 00:00:00'): 98.997117000000003,  pd.Timestamp('2015-03-02 00:00:00'): 100.0,  pd.Timestamp('2015-05-11 00:00:00'): 102.518433,  pd.Timestamp('2015-03-04 00:00:00'): 98.909215000000003, pd.Timestamp('2015-05-13 00:00:00'): 103.424257,  pd.Timestamp('2015-04-06 00:00:00'):  np.nan})})
```

```
print (df)

                     b
2015-02-25         NaN
2015-03-02  100.000000
2015-03-03   98.997117
2015-03-04   98.909215
2015-04-05         NaN
2015-04-06         NaN
2015-04-09  100.502772
2015-04-10  101.685314
2015-05-11  102.518433
2015-05-12  102.427237
2015-05-13  103.424257
2015-06-16  102.669184
2015-06-17         NaN
2015-06-18  102.436339
2015-07-19  102.672482
2015-07-20  102.238386
2015-08-23  101.460082
```

```
def f(x):
    if x.first_valid_index() is None:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x[x.first_valid_index()]

print (df.b.groupby(df.index.to_period('M')).apply(f))
2015-02           NaN
2015-03    100.000000
2015-04    100.502772
2015-05    102.518433
2015-06    102.669184
2015-07    102.672482
2015-08    101.460082
Freq: M, Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Comment: is it relevant where this `NaN` value is? Because they're not necessarily at the start (usually on weekends, really)#

Comment: It return first non `NaN` value for each month. Do you want it?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want. The issue I have now is that it seems to not keep my dates in the index of my `Series`. Do I have to glue that together separately, or is there a neat way to work around this?

Comment: I think it is problem, because you groupby by `months`, so indexes are months (1,2..12)

Comment: I add sample, please check it.

Comment: Raises a `TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable` - [see here](http://pastebin.com/1NKVbdJQ) for entire output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113024/discussion-between-jezrael-and-j4ck).