# df.first_valid_index() returns an index which raises a KeyError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to group a `pd.DataFrame` by month and apply a custom function `ultimo(x)`:

```
def ultimo(x):
    if x.first_valid_index() is None:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x[x.first_valid_index()]
```

I've got this from another [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37456532/applying-custom-function-while-grouping-returns-nan). However, today I've encountered an `KeyError` while applying it - it claims that the returned index is not inside the index?

[Sample DataFrame as input](http://pastebin.com/wKDRvdD7)

I have printed what x and x.first_valid_index() returns as well:

```
x.index: <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
x.index.values: ['2015-03-30T02:00:00.000000000+0200' '2015-03-31T02:00:00.000000000+0200'] <class 'numpy.ndarray'> of type <class 'numpy.datetime64'>
x.first_valid_index(): 2015-03-30 00:00:00 <class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

I've converted my date index to datetime using `pd.to_datetime` prior to running `navs = navs.groupby(navs.index.to_period('M')).apply(ultimo)`:

```
navs['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(navs['Date'])
navs = navs.set_index('Date')
```

How can I fix this? It seems ironic that `pd.first_valid_index()` returns an index that raises a `KeyError`. My guess is that I have to do some other conversion on my index first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in your previous question, the input (and hence `x`) is a series, so `x[index]` works as expected. For a dataframe, `x[index]` expects a column name. In order to access the row indexed by the index, you need `x.loc[index]`. See [documentation here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label).

This function will work:

```
def ultimo(x):
    if x.first_valid_index() is None:
        return np.nan
    else:
        return x.loc[x.first_valid_index()]
```